How to work around SpringSessionBackedReactiveSessionRegistry bug? (Spring Security, Spring Session)
Any suggestions on how to work around the below bug, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Whenever I do something like val contextAttr = session.getAttribute<Map<String, Any>>(springAttribute), the contextAttr definitely comes back as a LinkedHashedMap.. These objects are stored in Redis as attributes to the main session, which I believe is all in JSON / Map <String, Any?> format.
Describe the bug
When my Spring logout handler calls this
fun invalidateSession(sessionId: String): Mono<Void> {
        logger.info("Invalidating sessionId: ${sessionId}")
        // handle the session invalidation process
        return reactiveSessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(sessionId)
            .flatMap { session ->
                // invalidate session
                session.invalidate()
                    .then(
                        // delete session
                        webSessionStore.removeSession(sessionId)
                    )
                    .doOnSuccess {
                        logger.info("Session invalidated and removed: ${sessionId}")
                    }
                    .doOnError { error ->
                        logger.error("Error invalidating session: ${sessionId}", error)
                    }
            }
    }

The following function inside SpringSessionBackedReactiveSessionRegistry gets called:
    @Override
    public Mono<ReactiveSessionInformation> getSessionInformation(String sessionId) {
        return this.sessionRepository.findById(sessionId).map(SpringSessionBackedReactiveSessionInformation::new);
    }

The inner class is implemented as follows:
class SpringSessionBackedReactiveSessionInformation extends ReactiveSessionInformation {

        SpringSessionBackedReactiveSessionInformation(S session) {
            super(resolvePrincipalName(session), session.getId(), session.getLastAccessedTime());
        }

        private static String resolvePrincipalName(Session session) {
            String principalName = session
                .getAttribute(ReactiveFindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME);
            if (principalName != null) {
                return principalName;
            }
            SecurityContext securityContext = session.getAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT);
            if (securityContext != null && securityContext.getAuthentication() != null) {
                return securityContext.getAuthentication().getName();
            }
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public Mono<Void> invalidate() {
            return super.invalidate()
                .then(Mono.defer(() -> SpringSessionBackedReactiveSessionRegistry.this.sessionRepository
                    .deleteById(getSessionId())));
        }

    }

But, here on this line:
SecurityContext securityContext = session.getAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT);
SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT is received from Redis as a HashMap or LinkedHashMap, so cannot be cast to SecurityContext (w/o proper de-serialisation)
This is EXACTLY the error I see:

Two calls to get session?
Also, I'm not sure if this is calling Redis again to get the security context, but is it necessary?, given just before calling /logout endpoint, the session / security context is retrieved anyway, (see below.)
SessionId would come from the session, here, when this is called in the line just before fun invalidateSession(sessionId: String): Mono ) (to get the session ID), so calling getSessionInformation(String sessionId) and with it, this.sessionRepository.findById(sessionId), again, seems a bit wasteful...?
To Reproduce
See above, just try the above, with sessions stored to redis, then try to invalidate a session calling the above functions
Expected behavior
The casting should be properly deserialised. A linkedHashmap cannot be cast to a SecurityContext object directly
Sample
See above. Github code can be found here:
My implementations
https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/blob/master/Spring%20BFF/BFF/src/main/kotlin/com/frontiers/bff/auth/sessions/SessionRegistryConfig.kt
Spring implementation (where error is I believe)
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/main/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/security/SpringSessionBackedReactiveSessionRegistry.java
Appreciate any help or suggestions given!

Have you included Spring Security's Jackson Modules? https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/configuration/reactive-redis-indexed.html#serializing-session-using-json

I believe so... look here: https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/blob/master/Spring%20BFF/bff/auth/serialisers/RedisSerialiserConfig.kt
